# How can I list files in reverse time order by a command and pass them as arguments to another command?

Tags: bash, files, date, arguments

I have a program which takes in some files as arguments in one command line. I would like to invoke it with   all the files in a directory listed in reverse time order.

For example:

I have following files in reverse time order in a directory

```
$ ls -tr
 Introduction.pdf  'Object-Oriented Data Model.pdf'
```

I can run my program straightforward,

```
myprogram Introduction.pdf  'Object-Oriented Data Model.pdf'
```

but I want to do the file listing by another command. This won't work because of the space in one file's name:

```
myprogram $(ls -tr)
```

I remember parsing `ls` output is not a good practice. I am not sure if `find` can help.

What can I do then?

Thanks.

Comment: why is `parsing ls` not good practice?  `ls -rt | myprogram` would work, the filename if it has a space would simply be `object-oriented\ data\ model.pdf` using a backslash before each space.  Or if `myprogram` is written in C you could use `popen("ls -rt", "r")` I do this all the time and it works great.

Comment: @ron why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Ron, using `ls ... | myprogram` would provide the filenames (as output from` ls`) as *stdin* to the program, not as arguments, as requested. Also note that any filename with a newline in it will be sent as two separate lines to the program, which would no longer be able to distinguish them from two separate filenames.

Comment: @roaima so you don't immediately -1 me.

Comment: what is `myprogram`?  A bash script, csh/tcsh script, ksh?  or is it an executable compiled from C code?  or python, java... ?

Comment: @ron I don't -1 answers just because they are offered alongside mine.

Answer (score 7):

If you've got reasonably up-to-date versions of the GNU utilities you can have them handle NULL-terminated data. This allows one to construct pipelines that are not affected by whitespace or newlines in the data itself.

My test tool is a quick script called `/tmp/args`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is args with $# value(s)"
for f in "$@"; do echo "> $f <"; done
```

This is how you can feed it a series of filenames on the command line, sorted by file time last modified:

```
find -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zn | sed -z 's/^[0-9.]* //' | xargs -0 /tmp/args
```

The `find` command prefixes each file/path name with a representation in fractional seconds of the date/time last modified. This is handled by `sort` to order from lowest (oldest) to highest (newest). The `sed` strips off the leading number we've just used to sort by, and the resulting set of filenames are passed to `xargs`. Replace the `%p` with `%P` if you prefer to omit the leading `./` from filenames.

Example data

```
# "c d" contains a space; "e f" contains a newline; "h" has leading whitespace
touch a 'e
f' g ' h ' 'c d' b
```

Example result

```
This is args with 6 value(s)
> ./a <
> ./e
f <
> ./g <
> ./ h  <
> ./c d <
> ./b <
```

Comment: As there is no indication that this "solution" is meant ironically, some newbie may reach the conclusion that this is how people sort files on unix -- by chaining a thousand commands, each of them using dubious non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Bash [doesn't yet make it easy to sort files by modification time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513494/117549), so here's the obligatory zsh-based answer. You don't have to switch to zsh as your login shell in order to use its features.

Here I set up a wrapper function that expects either one or two arguments; the first argument is the program to execute (e.g. `myprogram`); the second, optional, argument is the directory containing the files that you want to pass to the program. If you don't specify a second argument, it defaults to the current directory.

```
zeio() {
  # Zsh-based Execute with files In Order
  [ -d "${2:-.}" ] || return
  zsh -c "$1 \"${2:-.}\"/*(.om)"
}
```

Name it whatever you like, of course. After a quick sanity-check of the second argument (again, defaulting to `.`, the current directory), we call zsh with a single double-quoted string that contains the program and some initial arguments (argument #1) and the directory (argument #2) — defaulting to `.` — with a wildcard / glob expansion that has two ["glob qualifiers"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) in the trailing parenthesis:

1. `.` -- must be regular files (not directories or symlinks, etc)
2. `om` -- `o`rder (sort) the resulting list by modification time, most recent first

It's that `om` glob qualifier that does all of the real work here.

Here's some sample runs; `myprog` is a simple shell script to demonstrate the arguments it receives, in order:

```
#!/bin/sh
for arg do
  printf 'Arg: ->%s<-\n' "$arg"
done
```

and `go.sh` is the file where I saved the function. The rest of the directory structure is:

```
$ tree .
.
├── dir1
│   ├── 203142
│   ├── 203143
│   └── 203144
├── dir3
│   ├── first\012filename
│   ├── this is 3rd
│   └── this is second
├── dir two
│   ├── 203225
│   ├── 203226
│   └── 203227
├── go.sh
└── myprog
```

... where I've created the sets of three files in each subdirectory in the listed sequence; I expect to see them in this same order when I execute the function. The first filename under dir3 has a newline in it, represented by `tree` with `\012`. The results are:

#### Demonstrating the default-to-current-directory behavior:

```
$ zeio ./myprog
Arg: ->./myprog<-
Arg: ->./go.sh<-
```

#### Normal filename demonstration

```
$ zeio ./myprog dir1
Arg: ->dir1/203142<-
Arg: ->dir1/203143<-
Arg: ->dir1/203144<-
```

#### Directory has a space in it

```
$ zeio ./myprog "dir two"
Arg: ->dir two/203225<-
Arg: ->dir two/203226<-
Arg: ->dir two/203227<-
```

#### filenames have whitespace in them

```
$ zeio ./myprog dir3
Arg: ->dir3/first
filename<-
Arg: ->dir3/this is second<-
Arg: ->dir3/this is 3rd<-
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(IFS=$'\n'; set -f; your_program $(ls -tr))
```

Assuming that the filenames don't contain newlines.

Example:

```
% touch 'a   b'
% touch 'c d'
% touch '*'
% (IFS=$'\n'; set -f; printf '%s\n' $(ls -tr))
e    f
a   b
c d
*
```

Variant for a standard shell which doesn't support `$'...'` strings:

```
(IFS='
' ; set -f; your_program $(ls -tr))
```

---

Simple python wrapper which will work even with filenames containing newlines. Usage can be `this_wrapper your_program *`.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

sys.argv[2:] = sorted(sys.argv[2:], key=os.path.getmtime)
os.execvp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the filenames contains newlines

Comment: Then this won't work ;-) -- and you'll have to use something like `perl` or `python`.

Comment: Thanks. How will you use Python?

Comment: I'm no python programmer, but since nobody steps in .... YMMV, that may not be the state of the art ;-)

Comment: Tim, do you really have newlines in your filenames?

Comment: @Freddy Rarely. But everything is possible.